# 10 Years of Unpaid Taxes

Tags: futurama

Farnsworth lied about his age and called the Sunset Squad because he didn't feel useful anymore.  Since he lied about his age, that would mean he didn't pay any taxes for the number of years he lied about(10). After he came back,  wouldn't the IRS find out that he lied about his age?

Why did Farnsworth get out of paying the IRS the taxes he owes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the Futurama Comic Issue 5:

Farnsworth actually was caught and was forced to pay about a million dollars to the IRS.  The million dollars would cause Planet Express to be bankrupt and force Farnsworth to sell everything.

Fry had to go to the "Who's dying to be a Gazillionaire", hosted by Morbo, to try to win the money to save Planet Express.